# Problems with pst-text package after ubuntu update

Tags: pstricks, texlive, ubuntu, updating

I just did a `do_release_upgrade` with my Ubuntu from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20, which of course also updated a lot of TeX. Since then, the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
% \def\pgfversion{42} %% Adding this doen't help
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

results in the following

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Loading [

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.10 \ProvidesPackageRCS[v
                          \pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf...

?
```

Apparently, `\pgfversion` is not (yet) defined when needed (inside the `\usepackage{pstricks}`) .

**Q:** What's wrong? no package seems to desire update.

As a workaround, I tried adding `\def\pgfversion{42}`, but that doesn't change anything, i.e., inside the `\usepackage`, the `\pgfversion` is still undefined.

---

**Edit:** I'm using TeX-live. For convenience, I replaced pst-text with the more immediate pstricks and added the *complete* output above in order to make the used filenames clear.

Comment: ??? What does pgf have to do with pstricks?

Comment: @Bernard It seems that `pstricks.sty` includes `pstricks.tex`, which again includes (among others) `pgffor.code.tex`, where the error happens

Comment: Yes, pstricks loads `pgffor`; yet I have no problem with it (I'm under MiKTeX – would it be a problem with Ubuntu, or with TeX Live??

Comment: For me the code compiles without problems with the Debian distribution of TeX Live 2019 under Ubuntu 20.04 (so the same as you have presumably), both with `latex` and `pdflatex`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when performing the same upgrade.

I was able to fix it by editing the file `/path/to/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex` and commenting out the line `\ProvidesPackageRCS[v\pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex,v 1.25 2013/12/13 11:40:27 tantau Exp $`